# Traceback (most recent call last) when docx.Document() is used

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

```
import docx

f = open('~/Desktop/python/test/draft.docx','rb')

document = docx.Document(f)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 56, in <module>
    document = docx.Document(f) 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docx/api.py", line 25, in Document
    document_part = Package.open(docx).main_document_part
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docx/opc/package.py", line 116, in open
    pkg_reader = PackageReader.from_file(pkg_file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docx/opc/pkgreader.py", line 32, in from_file
    phys_reader = PhysPkgReader(pkg_file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docx/opc/phys_pkg.py", line 101, in __init__
    self._zipf = ZipFile(pkg_file, 'r')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1200, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1267, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

1. Uninstalled docx and installed python-docx
2. Uninstalled lxml too
   None of it works.

Any help would be appreciated
Running python3.7 on OS X10.13

Comment: Edit your Question and show us the output of `file draft.docx` in a console.

Answer (score 0):

Don't open the file before you pass it to `Document()`. Just give it the path like you did in the `open()` call above.

It needs to be an actual Word .docx file. Note that you can just call `document = Document()` to get started. The "save as" file name is provided in the `document.save()` call. The file (if any) provided in the `Document()` call is just the starting-point "template" to use.

See the related documentation here:
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html

Comment: sorted out the issue. The draft.docx file was corrupted somehow. Changed the file and it worked.
document = docx.Document('draft.docx') also worked.